# Resizing a UITextField programmatically automatically reverts back to old size

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiview, autolayout

After a certain user action I wish to resize a `UITextField` and move it to the right: e.g.

```
CGRect oldFrame = self.sampleTextField.frame;
CGRect newFrame = CGRectMake(oldFrame.origin.x + 100,
                             oldFrame.origin.y, 
                             oldFrame.size.width - 100, 
                             oldFrame.size.height);
[self.sampleTextField setFrame:newFrame];
```

This works for about half a second and then the `UITextField` snaps back into it's original, unedited frame.

The `UITextField` is put in place in a storyboard but I have removed all auto-layout constraints from it.

Is it auto-layout that is returning the `UITextField` to it's original frame?

Is there a way of achieving this with my current setup or will I have to take the `UITextField` out of the storyboard and programmatically add it to the View?

Comment: If you're using AutoLayout you should adjust the constraints instead of adjusting the frame.

Comment: Show us everywhere that you manipulate `sampleTextField`.

Comment: @Jonathan I considered that but I find programmatically adjusting constraints to be very very tricky, hence I asked the question the way I asked it!

Comment: @CrimsonChris That is all the manipulation that I do on `sampleTextField`

Comment: Is there a reason why you're not using `self.sampleTextField` inside the `CGRectMake`?

Comment: @CrimsonChris Apologies, typo in the sample code. Fixed now.

Comment: @messinga It looks like you are still accessing some backing variable directly instead of using the `sampleTextField` getter.

Comment: @CrimsonChris Thanks for pointing that out. Sample code is fixed again.

Comment: @messinga, all you have to do is adjust the constant value. Unless you absolutely need to remove the constraints and re-add them. For instance, you are adding 100 to the X axis so you can set the leading(left) constraint's constant to += 100. You are also subtracting 100 from the width so all you need to do is set the width constraint's constant to -= 100. Then, you can animate the change if needed. Of course this all depends on the constraints that you currently have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you build and run without adding any constraints to an element, you’ll find that Interface Builder **fixes the element’s width and height**, and **pins** its position relative to the top left corner of the superview.

To make your interface react correctly to changes in size or orientation, you need to start adding constraints. You can also remove the automatically added constraints programmatically before you set the frame and set `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` to `NO`.

Comment: Well that answers my first query on what the Interface Builder is doing with autolayout ... good to know. Unfortunately `setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO` does seem to resolve the exact issue but it will cause further issues to the rest of the view.

Comment: Following your suggestion on `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` ... I wrapped the `UITextField` in a `UIView` and then set `setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO` on the wrapper `UIView`. It seems to have done the trick. Not a very elegant solution but it works. I'll wait to see if someone has a better solution before marking the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to accomplish what you want is to add the proper constraints in IB (left edge, top or bottom edge, and width), and make IBOutlets to the left constraint and the width constraint (I'll call them leftCon and widthCon). In code, you then adjust the constant value of those constraints,

```
self.leftCon.constant += 100;
self.widthCon.constant -= 100;
```

If you want to animate that, then put them in (or just above, it works either way) an animation block,

```
- (void)adjustTextField {
    self.leftCon.constant += 100;
    self.widthCon.constant -= 100;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1 animations:^{
        [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
    }];
}
```